# Can IIS6 compression file types be configured on a per-site basis?

Tags: iis, iis-6, compression

The following article explains how to customise the file types that can be compressed in IIS 6:

[Customizing the File Types IIS Compresses (IIS 6.0) [MS TechNet]](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/5bce429d-c4a7-4f9e-a619-5972497b932a.mspx?mfr=true)

The metabase settings discussed are global settings.

Can I configure this on a per-site basis?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some digging about it looks like this is a global setting and can only be configured at the following metabase location:

`/LM/W3SVC/Filters/Compression/gzip`
`/LM/W3SVC/Filters/Compression/deflate`

For more info:

> [HcFileExtensions - MSDN Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525337(v=VS.90).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can.

See "To enable HTTP Compression for Individual Sites and Site Elements" [here](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/502ef631-3695-4616-b268-cbe7cf1351ce.mspx?mfr=true).

Edit: I misread the details of the question. I am pretty sure I have configured different file extensions for compression on different sites in the past, but I also can't seem to find any definitive answer right now. I'll check when I'm at work tomorrow.

Comment: I read that. That's just the settings to turn on/off compression by site. There's no mention about whether you can customise the file types on a site by site basis.